# SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, concatenation

Sorry for my English...

I Iave a table with column

```
project, month, year
abc      2      2017
xyz      5      2017
abc      3      2017
abc      5      2017
abc      1      2018
```

How can I search  project **abc** with month = 2 year = 2017 **until** month = 1 year = 2018

As far as I know, SQL Server 2008 cannot use concat function

Comment: What have you tried?  You can accomplish this with basic sql using a `where` statement.  Look at `>=` and `<=`. . .

Comment: could you show me how it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use math comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE (year * 12 + month) BETWEEN (2017 * 12 + 1) AND (2018 * 12 + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks verymuch @forpas i didnt see ur answer b4..
it works and help me alot

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select  *
From    YourTable
Where   DATETIMEFROMPARTS(year, month, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) 
  between '2017-02-01' And '2018-01-01'
```

Comment: Good answer, but DateTimeFromParts was not present in SQL 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the code to account for the leading zero in the month.

```
Declare     @temp Table 
    (
        project varchar(50), 
        month   int, 
        year    int 
    );

Insert  Into    @temp 
        (project, month, year) 
Values  ('abc', 2, 2017) 

Insert  Into    @temp 
        (project, month, year) 
Values  ('xyz', 5, 2017) 

Insert  Into    @temp 
        (project, month, year) 
Values  ('abc', 3, 2017) 

Insert  Into    @temp 
        (project, month, year) 
Values  ('abc', 5, 2017) 

Insert  Into    @temp 
        (project, month, year) 
Values  ('abc', 1, 2018) 

Insert  Into    @temp 
        (project, month, year) 
Values  ('xxx', 5, 2010) 

Insert  Into    @temp 
        (project, month, year) 
Values  ('xxx', 12, 2018) 


Declare @FromYear   int = 2010;
Declare @FromMonth  int = 04;
Declare @ToYear     int = 2018; 
Declare @ToMonth    int = 05;

Select  *  
From    @temp  
Where   Convert(varchar, year) + right('00' + Convert(varchar, month), 2) Between '201004' and '201805'
```

Comment: Quick Question...Noob here. Does a variable assign a changeable value which could be used redundantly whether user session ends or not?

Comment: Not sure I  understand the question. You can certainly change a variables value using Set but it won't be valid past a GO or end of batch.

Comment: thanks @jonvote, but still no success here..ex  if i:

Declare FromYear   int = 2010;
Declare FromMonth  int = 04;
Declare ToYear     int = 2018; 
Declare ToMonth    int = 05;

Select  * 
From    JonTest  
Where   Convert(varchar, year) + Convert(varchar, month) Between '201004' and '201805'

it showing date from month 05 year 2010 until month 12  year 2018

Comment: via.becker - Sorry - I forgot to take into account the leading zero in the month. I have corrected the code above. But I also believe that the solution from forpas would also work.

Comment: jon vote - Thanks mate, i guess i'll take forpas solution..i do appreciate yours

Answer (score 0):

> How can I search project abc with month = 2 year = 2017 until month = 1 year = 2018

You can use

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE (([Year] * 10) + [Month]) BETWEEN 20172 AND 20181
      AND
      project = 'abc';
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e7909df957ab3628bc309aa59cb9f22b)**

Comment: Thanks sam..but i've already solve this..thanks for your help though